# Jquery custom images slider only works once or the third time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple images slider. The problem I'm facing is that the next and prev buttons only work the first time. Then when you hover an item again it doesn't work. When you hover an item the third time it works, and so on.

I just can't find what's causing this behaviour.

**Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meules/4h7yk3jx/44/)**

```
$('.item.with-sec-image').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  /* load data only once */
  if (!$this.hasClass('images-initialized')) {
    var url = $this.data('handle').replace('.html', '.ajax');
    var purl = $this.data('handle');
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      if (data.images.length > 1) {
        var slider = $this.find('.slider');
        if (data.images.length >= 2 && data.images.length != slider.find('li.selected').length) {
          $.each(data.images, function(index, image) {
            var img_url = image.replace('50x50x2', '400x400x2')
            if (slider.find('li.selected').data('index') != index) {
              var $newImage = $('<li><a href="' + purl + '"><img src="' + img_url + '" /></a></li>')
              slider.append($newImage);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }).done(function() {
      $this.addClass('images-initialized');
    });
  }
  $this.on('click', '.slider-btn', function() {
    updateSlider($this)
  });
});
```

The function to update the slider

```
function updateSlider(navigation) {
  var $this = navigation
  var sliderContainer = $this.find('.images .slider'),
    activeSlider = sliderContainer.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');

  if ($this.hasClass('next')) {
    (!activeSlider.is(':last-child')) ? activeSlider.next().addClass('selected'): sliderContainer.children('li').eq(0).addClass('selected');
  } else {
    (!activeSlider.is(':first-child')) ? activeSlider.prev().addClass('selected'): sliderContainer.children('li').last().addClass('selected');
  }
}
```

And, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="item with-sec-image" data-handle="some-url">

  <div class="images">
    <ul class="slider">
      <li data-index="0" class="selected"><img src="link-to-image" /></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="slider-navigation">
      <li class="prev btn-round slider-btn small"><i class="icon-left"></i></li>
      <li class="next btn-round slider-btn small"><i class="icon-right"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.item.with-sec-image').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  /* load data only once */
  if (!$this.hasClass('images-initialized')) {
    var url = $this.data('handle').replace('.html', '.ajax');
    var purl = $this.data('handle');
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      if (data.images.length > 1) {
        var slider = $this.find('.slider');
        if (data.images.length >= 2 && data.images.length != slider.find('li.selected').length) {
          $.each(data.images, function(index, image) {
            var img_url = image.replace('50x50x2', '400x400x2')
            if (slider.find('li.selected').data('index') != index) {
              var $newImage = $('<li><a href="' + purl + '"><img src="' + img_url + '" /></a></li>')
              slider.append($newImage);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }).done(function() {
      $this.addClass('images-initialized');
    });
  }
  $this.on('click', '.slider-btn', function() {
    updateSlider($this)
  });
});

// The function to update the slider

function updateSlider(navigation) {
  var $this = navigation
  var sliderContainer = $this.find('.images .slider'),
    activeSlider = sliderContainer.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');

  if ($this.hasClass('next')) {
    (!activeSlider.is(':last-child')) ? activeSlider.next().addClass('selected'): sliderContainer.children('li').eq(0).addClass('selected');
  } else {
    (!activeSlider.is(':first-child')) ? activeSlider.prev().addClass('selected'): sliderContainer.children('li').last().addClass('selected');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item with-sec-image" data-handle="some-url">

  <div class="images">
    <ul class="slider">
      <li data-index="0" class="selected"><img src="link-to-image" /></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="slider-navigation">
      <li class="prev btn-round slider-btn small"><i class="icon-left"></i></li>
      <li class="next btn-round slider-btn small"><i class="icon-right"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this has a lot of guess job. Give us a live example like the code snippet below, or an actual URL with non minified js to see the problem

Comment: @JohnPan: Yes you're right. I'll create a fiddle

Comment: @JohnPan: I've added a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured out the problem.

your are binding the click event on `mouseenter` which mean that it will be bind many time. so one click will equal multiple clicks and that why you are encountering this behavior.

I have made small changes to your code look below. and also here is [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/wmjxap4b/) working example

```js
 function updateSlider(btn) {
   var $this = btn.closest(".item.with-sec-image");
   var sliderContainer = $this.find('.images .slider'),
     activeSlider = sliderContainer.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');

   if (btn.hasClass('next')) {
     (!activeSlider.is(':last-child')) ? activeSlider.next().addClass('selected'): sliderContainer.children('li').eq(0).addClass('selected');
   } else {
     (!activeSlider.is(':first-child')) ? activeSlider.prev().addClass('selected'): sliderContainer.children('li').last().addClass('selected');
   }
 }

  // second image only on hover
$(function(){

   $('.item.with-sec-image').on('mouseenter', function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (!$this.hasClass('images-initialized')) {
       var url = $this.data('handle').replace('.html', '.ajax');
       var purl = $this.data('handle');
       $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         if (data.images.length > 1) {
           var slider = $this.find('.slider');
           if (data.images.length >= 2 && data.images.length != slider.find('li.selected').length) {
             $.each(data.images, function(index, image) {
               var img_url = image.replace('50x50x2', '400x400x2')
               if (slider.find('li.selected').data('index') != index) {
                 var $newImage = $('<li><a href="' + purl + '"><img src="' + img_url + '" /></a></li>')
                 slider.append($newImage);
               }
             });
           }
         }
       }).done(function() {
         $this.addClass('images-initialized');
       });
     }

   }).on('click', '.slider-btn', function() {// this should be run outside the mouseenter function or else it will bind many times
       updateSlider($(this))
     });
 });
```

Comment: This makes sense... Why haven't I thought about that :( It works, thx for the help!!

Comment: Np, this is programming we always miss things when we are coding.

Comment: I have to wait 2 hours before I can send the bounty. It will come your way!!